# wxPython: Can a wx.PyControl contain a wx.Sizer?

Tags: python, wxpython, custom-controls, widget, sizer

Can a `wx.PyControl` contain a `wx.Sizer`?

Note that what I am ultimately trying to do here (spinner with float values) is already answered in another question. I am particularly interested in layouting widgets within a `wx.PyControl`, a skill which might prove useful if I come across a need to make my own custom widgets. I already read through [CreatingCustomControls](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls), but it didn't use sizers within the `wx.PyControl` subclass.

Using my code below, my `CustomWidget` just doesn't look right. I'm not yet doing a `DoGetBestSize` because I think that applies to a `wx.Sizer` acting **on** a widget. I am actually having a `wx.Sizer` doing its thing **inside** a `CustomWidget`.

Here is my code (without the event bindings between sub-widgets):
**EDIT:** Here is my corrected class code, thanks to [Steven Sproat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271639/wxpython-can-a-wx-pycontrol-contain-a-wx-sizer/3272377#3272377):

```
import wx

class CustomWidget(wx.PyControl):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent=parent, style=wx.NO_BORDER) # Style added.
    text = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self)
    spin = wx.SpinButton(parent=self, style=wx.SP_VERTICAL)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
    self.layout(text, spin, sizer)
    self.OnInit(text, sizer)

  def OnInit(self, text, sizer):
    text.SetValue(u"0.000")

  def layout(self, text, spin, sizer):
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    sizer.Add(text, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    sizer.Add(spin, pos=(0, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    self.Fit()
    self.Layout() # This is what I lacked. I needed to call .Layout()
    self.CenterOnParent()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. You just need to call Layout() to tell the sizer to recalculate/layout its children.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
    blah  = CustomWidget(self)
    self.Show(True)

class CustomWidget(wx.PyControl):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    text = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self)
    spin = wx.SpinButton(parent=self, style=wx.SP_VERTICAL)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
    self.layout(text, spin, sizer)
    self.OnInit(text, sizer)

  def OnInit(self, text, sizer):
    text.SetValue(u"0.000")

  def layout(self, text, spin, sizer):
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    sizer.Add(text, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    sizer.Add(spin, pos=(0, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    self.Fit()
    self.Layout()
    self.CenterOnParent()

app = wx.App()
f = Frame()
app.MainLoop()
```

By the way, it would be nice in the future if you could attach a runnable sample as above :)

Comment: This is excellent! And thanks for the community tip about the runnable sample. I'll do so next time :) I also edited my question to include your solution.

Comment: I did a few more experiments with this one, but I think it breaks down when the `CustomWidget` is a child of a `wx.Panel`, instead of a `wx.Frame`. Your thoughts?

Comment: did you try as Robin suggested?

Comment: Yes I tried that, too. I composed a [new question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308485/wxpython-wx-pycontrol-layout-problem-when-it-is-a-child-of-a-wx-panel)

Answer (score 1):

Since classes derived from wxControl are not normally used for containing other widgets the auto-layout code is not present and so it will not call Layout() when it gets the EVT_SIZE event.  You can easily add that ability to your class by Bind()ing a handler for EVT_SIZE and calling self.Layout() from there.  Then it will act just like a panel does when it gets the size event and has children and a sizer.