# wxPython: wx.PyControl layout problem when it is a child of a wx.Panel

Tags: python, wxpython, custom-controls, widget, sizer

This is a continuation from this question:
[wxPython: Can a wx.PyControl contain a wx.Sizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271639/wxpython-can-a-wx-pycontrol-contain-a-wx-sizer)

The main topic here is using a `wx.Sizer` inside a `wx.PyControl`. I had problems `Fit()`ting my `CustomWidget` around its child widgets. That problem was solved by calling `Layout()` after `Fit()`.

**However**, as far as I have experienced, the solution only works when the `CustomWidget` is a direct child of a `wx.Frame`. It breaks down when it becomes a child of a `wx.Panel`.

**EDIT:** Using the code below, the `CustomWidget` doesn't resize correctly to fit its children. I observed that this only happens when the `CustomWidget` (as a subclass of `wx.PyControl`) is a child of a `wx.Panel`; otherwise, if it is a direct child of a `wx.Frame`, it `Fit()`s perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)
    panel = Panel(parent=self)
    custom = CustomWidget(parent=panel)
    self.Show()

class Panel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.SetSize(parent.GetClientSize())

class CustomWidget(wx.PyControl):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    # Create the sizer and make it work for the CustomWidget        
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

    # Create the CustomWidget's children
    text = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self)
    spin = wx.SpinButton(parent=self, style=wx.SP_VERTICAL)

    # Add the children to the sizer        
    sizer.Add(text, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    sizer.Add(spin, pos=(0, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

    # Make sure that CustomWidget will auto-Layout() upon resize
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
    self.Fit()

  def OnSize(self, event):
    self.Layout()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = Frame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What happens to the widget? You don't need to set the size of the panel since it's the frame's only child. It will fit the frame all by itself.

Comment: It's fine to refer to the other question, but could you state clearly here what you want to happen.

Comment: @tom10: Thanks, I added details of my objective.  
@Mike: I think it is still necessary to `SetSize()` a panel which is an only child. Try doing a `GetSize()` and you'll get `(20, 20)` if you don't do a `SetSize()`, and this won't play well with children that `CenterOnParent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)` does the job. I'm not sure why a `.SetSizer(sizer)` then a `.Fit()` won't work. Any ideas?

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)
    panel = Panel(parent=self)
    custom = CustomWidget(parent=panel)
    self.Show()

class Panel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.SetSize(parent.GetClientSize())

class CustomWidget(wx.PyControl):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    # Create the sizer and make it work for the CustomWidget        
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

    # Create the CustomWidget's children
    text = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self)
    spin = wx.SpinButton(parent=self, style=wx.SP_VERTICAL)

    # Add the children to the sizer        
    sizer.Add(text, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    sizer.Add(spin, pos=(0, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

    # Set sizer and fit, then layout
    self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
    self.Layout()

  # ------------------------------------------------------------
  #  # Make sure that CustomWidget will auto-Layout() upon resize
  #  self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
  #  self.Fit()
  #  
  #def OnSize(self, event):
  #  self.Layout()
  # ------------------------------------------------------------    

app = wx.App(False)
frame = Frame()
app.MainLoop()
```